# Cannot find inspections in Intellij 12.1.4

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am not able to find the 'Missing @Override annotation' in Settings|Project Settings|Inspections|Class Structure. The page at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/inspections.jsp shows more than 20 inspections for Class Structure but I am only seeing 2. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have **Inspection Gadgets** plug-in enabled:

[image: ig]

Comment: That solved my problem. Thanks. I am new to IntelliJ. Was a Eclipse user for 10 years.